Different versions of the text of The Story of Doctor Dolittle?
In the process of answering this question, I hunted high and low for a quote that I was sure I remembered from the original book The Story of Doctor Dolittle which remarked explicitly on the doctor's surname and its connotations. Unfortunately, I don't have any physical copies of the book to hand any more, so I couldn't check the actual story that I read in my childhood. Searching online, I found an excerpt used for a reading comprehension test which included some sentences that were not in the Project Gutenberg or Wikisource versions of the text. We now have two imperfect pieces of evidence that the text of the story has different versions: my possibly-unreliable memory, and the not-clearly-sourced text at Einstein 11 Plus.
Were there different published versions of the book in which small details like this could have been changed? Wikipedia mentions that it was edited to remove racist and colonialist elements, but commentary on the name "Dolittle" doesn't seem to be related to such concerns.

This seems to be the original book: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Doctor_Dolittle I don't think those versions were bowdlerized.

In Chapter 11, The Black Prince, the prince, who is black,  wants to be white. Is that the sort of thing you are after? "Oh tell me, Fairy-Queen,” cried Bumpo, clasping his hands in joy, “who is it can turn me white?”

@Lambie I'm asking whether there were other changes than the ones relating to race and colonialism, or perhaps different versions of the book published before those race-related changes.

You say "small details like this". Sorry, but like what?

There seems to be a longer extract of the comprehension test version here: https://iswkoman.com/uploads/spaper/6433625-MIDTERM%20ASSESSMENT%20%202023-24.pdf which specifically states it was "extracted and adapted" from The Story of Dr Dolittle, but no mention who by.

@Lambie Like "a quote that I was sure I remembered from the original book ... which remarked explicitly on the doctor's surname and its connotations."
